# calculating remaining days with daylight saving using JODA API

Tags: java, android, calendar, jodatime, android-calendar

I have a requirement like calculating the days between two dates and calculating the future date by adding the weeks/months to the date. I used java.util.Calendar; and
java.util.Date. these are not giving accurate results, it fails in daylight saving issue. so i decided to use JODA calendar API. I am very new to JODA API. Please anyone provide me sample code to calculate the below requirements.

1).noOfDays(String currDate, String tarDate)
2).addMonths(String date, int months)
3).addDays(String date, int days)
4).futureDate(String date,int week)

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: Have you already looked through the Joda Time API? How far have you got? Why are you using `String` to represent dates in the first place? What is your `futureDate` method meant to do?

Comment: I have started looking just now, i am getting the date from a text field with string format like "12/12/2012" ,the futureDate  method would give the the date which occurring in future time by adding weeks to date.

Comment: So why isn't it called `addWeeks` like `addDays` and `addMonths`? Also, isolate the text handling from everything else - the *first* thing to do is parse the date (e.g. into a `LocalDate`).

Comment: @Ganesh I have written this [Joda-Time Tutorial](http://www.ayp-sd.blogspot.com/2012/12/joda-time-tutorial_7.html) to address a couple of frequent use-cases with Joda-Time. Theoretical part is mostly based on the documentation, so you can skip it and go directly to examples. If you just started exploring Joda-Time API it might be useful to you.

Comment: Very nice tutorial, it saved me a lot of time. Great Thanks @ Andrey Polunin

Answer (score 1):

0) To convert String to Date use
[DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
For example, if you date looks like `"31/12/2012"`

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");  
DateTime date = dtf.parseDateTime("31/12/2012");
```

this class [ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) contains formatters for basic date formats.
1) To calculate days between two dates, use method [Days#daysBetween](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29)
for examle

```
DateTime date1 = dtf.parseDateTime("31/12/2012");    
DateTime date2 = dtf.parseDateTime("15/11/2012");  
int daysbetween = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2);
```

2) To add months to date use [DateTime#plusMonths()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMonths%28int%29)

```
DateTime newDate = dtf.parseDateTime("31/12/2012").plusMonths(5);
```

3) To add days to date use method `DateTime#plusDays()`
4) To add weeks to date use method `DateTime#plusWeeks()`
Also you can use [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class instead of [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) if you are using date without time

Comment: How to calculate the difference between passed date and future date.i,e which gives the -ve days result.

Comment: @Ganesh Days.daysBetween(passedDate, futureDate);